# How can MacOSX 10.9.1 Safari tabs be used to merge two single tabbed windows?

Tags: macos, firefox, safari, browser-tabs, osx-spaces

Trying to come up with a complete picture as to how to use these new Displays and Spaces, especially with some of the Applications which supposedly were designed to utilize this new paradigm.

Noticed this some time back, but this becomes a major annoyance with the new Display and Spaces paradigm:

Given 2 Safari windows, both with a single tab, how do I drag the tab from the one Window to join the tab of the other?  This works fine in Firefox, but fails miserably with Safari.  To get this to work, and this workaround isn't really useful:  Use a 3rd Safari window that already has 2 open tabs as a base Safari window to get the other 2 tabs incorporated into that window's view - yuck!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default safari hides the tab when it is the only one open.

To fix:

Open a safari window with only 1 tab
View -> Show Tab Bar

Now your windows will always show a tab and you can drag from one to the other without having to do the 4 tab hokey pokey.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29868/how-do-i-get-safari-5-1-to-always-display-the-tab-bar[image]

Comment: I just tried it on my dual monitors running safari 7.0.1 on Maveriks 10.9.1. Moving the tab both directions worked for me. Could you post a video of this not working?

Comment: This works. Indeed, though by default, it looks like there are tabs, pressing `shift-command-t` does yield what is a _real tab_, and it is all good.  Thanks.

Comment: As I alluded to in the first paragraph, with respect to Displays and Spaces, is there a way to easily get a tab from a full screen Safari window (allocated to surfing), into another full screen Safari window (allocated to programming)?  Got the from visible window with tabs to another down.  Now for the question that lead to this question - how to do it in the more general Displays/Spaces case?

Comment: Full screen tries to get out of the way as much as possible. As of version 7.0.1 full screen overrides the "Show tabs bar" option. It will require a change from apple to fix that. You can open feature requests here: http://www.apple.com/feedback/safari.html

Comment: It's a balance between coming up to speed with the environment and realizing that a new feature indeed is necessary. Will hold off on the feature request until I get the environment down i.e. the interrelation as to how it assigns Applications to Desktops to Displays, and then, how they interact, and how I fit all this into my TMUX/screen way of doing things. Right now, i've got TOO MANY WINDOWS. I'm ready to go back to a VT220 emulator until my sanity returns.  :-D